# Backpropagation and training set for dummies

Tags: neural-network, xor, backpropagation, perceptron

I'm at the very beginning of studying neural networks but my scarce skills or lack of intelligence do not allow me to understand from popular articles how to correctly prepare training set for backpropagation training method (or its limitations). For example, I want to train the simplest two-layer perceptron to solve XOR with backpropagation (e. g. modify random initial weights for 4 synapses from first layer and 4 from second). Simple XOR function has two inputs, one output: {0,0}=>0, {0,1}=>1, {1,0}=>1, {1,1}=>0. But neural networks theory tells that "backpropagation requires a known, desired output for each input value in order to calculate the loss function gradient". Does it means that backpropagation can't be applied if in training set amount of inputs is not strictly equal to amount of outputs and this restriction can not be avoided? Or does it means, if I want to use backpropagation for solving such classification tasks as XOR (i. e. number of inputs is bigger than number of outputs), theory tells that it's always necessary to remake training set in the similarly way (input=>desired output): {0,0}=>{0,0}, {0,1}=>{1,1}, {1,0}=>{1,1}, {1,1}=>{0,0}?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Does it means that backpropagation can't be applied if in training set amount of inputs is not strictly equal to amount of outputs

If you mean the output is "the class" in classification task, I don't think so,

> backpropagation requires a known, desired output for each input value in order to calculate the loss function gradient

I think it's mean every input should have an output, not a different output.

In real life problem, like handwriting digit classification (MNIST), there are around 50.000 data training (input), but only classed to 10 digit